# How can I configure Rspec to raise error when stubbing or mocking non-existing methods?

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

Is there a way that I can configure RSpec to raise an error when I am trying to stub/mock a non-existing method.

So, If I have the class

```
class A
  def foo
  end
end
```

and I write something like:

```
describe A do
  describe '#foo' do
    it 'foos' do
      expect(subject).to receive(foo2)
      # fire
      subject.foo
    end
  end
end
```

then RSpec will fail on first line

```
expect(subject....
```

by telling me that `:foo2` is not message that `subject` responds to.

Comment: Iirc there's a gem for that, the problem is that a method might be added after the mocking.

Comment: `raise unless subject.respond_to?(:foo2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality was introduced in the [rspec-fire gem](https://github.com/xaviershay/rspec-fire) and was recently ported into RSpec 3 (currently in beta) as described in [this github issue](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/pull/378). It is documented in https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/verifying-doubles